# Error in Html.DisplayNameFor()

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning  Entity Framework in MVC from

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8f4P8U1a2TI

in Index View ,it give following Error :

CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor and

'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor,MvcApplication1.Models.Department>

Index View :

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Employee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div style="font-family">
    <h2>
        Index</h2>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
</div>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th> </th>

    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>  @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.Name)   </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Employee Controller :

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private EmployeeContext1 db = new EmployeeContext1();

        //
        // GET: /Employee/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var employees = db.Employees.Include("Department");
            return View(employees.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Employee/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Single(e => e.Id == id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(employee);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Employee/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Employee/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Employees.AddObject(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name", employee.DepartmentId);
            return View(employee);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Employee/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Single(e => e.Id == id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name", employee.DepartmentId);
            return View(employee);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Employee/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Employees.Attach(employee);
                db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(employee, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name", employee.DepartmentId);
            return View(employee);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Employee/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Single(e => e.Id == id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(employee);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Employee/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Single(e => e.Id == id);
            db.Employees.DeleteObject(employee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

AutoGenerated Model Class :

```
  public partial class Employee : EntityObject
    {
        #region Factory Method

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new Employee object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Initial value of the Id property.</param>
        public static Employee CreateEmployee(global::System.Int32 id)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.Id = id;
            return employee;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Primitive Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.Int32 Id
        {
            get
            {
                return _Id;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_Id != value)
                {
                    OnIdChanging(value);
                    ReportPropertyChanging("Id");
                    _Id = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                    ReportPropertyChanged("Id");
                    OnIdChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private global::System.Int32 _Id;
        partial void OnIdChanging(global::System.Int32 value);
        partial void OnIdChanged();

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                OnNameChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Name");
                _Name = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Name");
                OnNameChanged();
            }
        }
        private global::System.String _Name;
        partial void OnNameChanging(global::System.String value);
        partial void OnNameChanged();

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String Gender
        {
            get
            {
                return _Gender;
            }
            set
            {
                OnGenderChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Gender");
                _Gender = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Gender");
                OnGenderChanged();
            }
        }
        private global::System.String _Gender;
        partial void OnGenderChanging(global::System.String value);
        partial void OnGenderChanged();

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String City
        {
            get
            {
                return _City;
            }
            set
            {
                OnCityChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("City");
                _City = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
                ReportPropertyChanged("City");
                OnCityChanged();
            }
        }
        private global::System.String _City;
        partial void OnCityChanging(global::System.String value);
        partial void OnCityChanged();

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Nullable<global::System.Int32> DepartmentId
        {
            get
            {
                return _DepartmentId;
            }
            set
            {
                OnDepartmentIdChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("DepartmentId");
                _DepartmentId = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("DepartmentId");
                OnDepartmentIdChanged();
            }
        }
        private Nullable<global::System.Int32> _DepartmentId;
        partial void OnDepartmentIdChanging(Nullable<global::System.Int32> value);
        partial void OnDepartmentIdChanged();

        #endregion


        #region Navigation Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("ComputerFirmModel", "FK__tblEmploy__Depar__4222D4EF", "tblDepartment")]
        public Department Department
        {
            get
            {
                return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Department>("ComputerFirmModel.FK__tblEmploy__Depar__4222D4EF", "tblDepartment").Value;
            }
            set
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Department>("ComputerFirmModel.FK__tblEmploy__Depar__4222D4EF", "tblDepartment").Value = value;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public EntityReference<Department> DepartmentReference
        {
            get
            {
                return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Department>("ComputerFirmModel.FK__tblEmploy__Depar__4222D4EF", "tblDepartment");
            }
            set
            {
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedReference<Department>("ComputerFirmModel.FK__tblEmploy__Depar__4222D4EF", "tblDepartment", value);
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

... Please Suggest

Comment: Where's the code of your Model?

Comment: But i believe Entity framework autoGenerate Model ..I have put model Code , which i was using for some additional functionality

Answer (score 3):

The error pretty much tells you exactly what the problem is. You've got a static extension class implementing `Html.DisplayNameFor`, while MVC has its own extension class implementing the same. You can't override extension methods, so you either need to make the names of your methods unique, or only load one or the other assembly. Since you can't *not* load MVC, that means you need to change the name of your method to something else like `Html.MyDisplayNameFor`.

Comment: There's no example code to give you. You've added a static class that extends `HtmlHelper` somewhere in your code, and unfortunately, it appears you've also clobbered the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace, so you can't use the namespace to help you track it down. Regardless, you need to change the method name in that class that is conflicting with the built in one from MVC, plain and simple.

Comment: OK ..1. Created MVC Project from Scracth ...2.Add EF 3. Add Employee Controller ... it Worked ...there was some garbage Code which i couldnot locate unfortunatelly